# Can GHC warn about the uses of dangerous non-total functions?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, crash, ghc, compiler-warnings

I have been writing quickly some code in Haskell, and used a dangerous non-total function, namely `fromJust` (where I expect a value from input). I'm going to think later what kind of error-handling style I want to use.

Can GHC help me make sure that I have got rid of all uses of dangerous non-total functions (like `fromJust` or `head`, which could crash) , give me warnings where they are.

Comment: Partiality inference is actually currently under discussion by the GHC devs. In the mean time, your best bet is probably to hide the imports of those functions, and (to make sure they're really hidden) redefine them yourself: `fromJust = ()` should do the trick.

Comment: Even just redefine them in a module, which you import unqualified as a way of "turning on the warning". You'll then get an ambiguity error pointing you at any places you actually use the Prelude's versions (unless you qualify then, as in `Prelude.fromJust`). It won't help for partial functions you use from qualified imports of other modules though.

Answer (score 3):

GHC can warn about definitions with partial patterns with `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` (though does not warn about uses of values that include incomplete patterns). Additionally, Neil Mitchell's [catch](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/catch/) attempts a slightly more detailed analysis to identify safe and unsafe invocations of partial functions. (Though of course that's an undecidable problem in general, so it won't always be right!)

Comment: Just a note for me. I came to the idea that whenever I want to use a non-total pattern match in a practically useful code (and I believe that semantically I exhaust all real cases), I shouldn't. In some cases it should be at least possible to make the assumption more explicit by wrapping the non-total function in a class and define it near the place where it is obvious that it is OK (as workaround for totally unsafe and uncontrollable code). Example: [a `ToJSONObject` constraint](https://github.com/bos/aeson/issues/79#issuecomment-108959252) for data encoded generically and deconstructed then.